# Error al acceder virtual host en xampp

Tags: apache, xampp

Tengo creado un virtual host con Apache y XAMPP. De forma local sí puedo acceder, pero si intento ingresar desde otro equipo y en la misma red no accede.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/project"
   ServerName devel.project
    ServerAlias devel.project
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile conf/ssl.crt/server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/ssl.key/server.key
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/project">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**¿Cuál puede ser el error?**

Comment: Sé que va a ser una pregunta básica, pero, ¿pones el servidor online para que pueda accederse desde otros equipos a través de la red?

Comment: Qué significa "no accede"? No accedes a ese virtual host en particular o directamente no se conecta? Si lo segundo, ten en cuenta que Apache debe escuchar en la ip 0.0.0.0 y que debes tener abierto ese puerto en tu firewall

Comment: No solo escribo el server name y no ingresa desde otro equipo

Comment: ¿Lo tienes desde una máquina virtual?

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te voy a dejar los pasos que yo sigo para crear mis virtual hosts (**WINDOWS**).

**1)** Ir a la siguiente dirección

> C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra

**2)** Modificar el archivo **httpd-vhosts.conf** añadiendo lo siguiente al final de el archivo y reemplazando el texto en mayusculas:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "DIRECCION DE TU PROYECTO"
    ServerName EJEMPLO.LOCALHOST
    <Directory "DIRECCION DE TU PROYECTO">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

**3)** Ir a la dirección

> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

y editar el archivo **hosts**, Despues de donde dice:

`127.0.0.1       localhost`

Cerca de la linea 23, Añadir lo siguiente:

`127.0.0.2       EJEMPLO.LOCALHOST`

**4)** Despues, Guarda y reemplaza el archivo, Ahora reinicia el apache desde XAMPP o MAMP, Y ya esta listo.

Comment: Añadiría un paso más para responder su pregunta del compañero, y esto porque en su configuración para el vhost tiene ya un **server alias** en ves de una **IP** y es la siguiente: 5.- Obtener la dirección **IP** que aloja el sitio Web mediante la consola `ipconfig` en windows o `ifconfig` so basados en linux. 5a.- El truco ahora es usar la dirección IP de la computadora a la que intentamos acceder / hablar: `192.168.1.5 devel.project` todo esto se puede revisar en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682262/how-do-i-connect-to-this-localhost-from-another-computer-on-the-same-network