# Error al acceder virtual host en xampp desde equipo en red

Tags: xampp, dns, virtualhost

Tengo el mismo problema consultado en [Error al acceder virtual host en xampp](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/14292/error-al-acceder-virtual-host-en-xampp).

El VirtualHost funciona perfectamente en el equipo que corre XAMPP, pero al acceder desde otro equipo de la red (portatil por wifi) al que se le ha modificado el archivo hosts (añadiendo: "192.168.1.2 dominio.local"), este accede al directorio raíz htdocs, y no al especificado en el DocumentRoot y DIRECTORY.
Por supuesto, la IP 192.168.1.2 es la dirección de red del que corre XAMPP.

En el virtualhost tengo:

```
<Directory "F:/locales/dominio/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost dominio.local:443>

DocumentRoot "F:/locales/dominio/"
ServerName dominio.local
ServerAlias www.dominio.local
ServerAdmin admin@dominio.net
ErrorLog "F:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "F:/xampp/apache/logs/access.log"

SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile "F:/xampp/apache/conf/mis_certificados/dominio.local/device.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "F:/xampp/apache/conf/mis_certificados/dominio.local/device.key"

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "F:/xampp/apache/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
CustomLog "F:/xampp/apache/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

Alguna idea?....
Gracias

Comment: Saludos lo que se debe hacer es en la PC dos (laptop) en el navegador colocar la IP de la PC 1 (con el proyecto php xampp) y automaticamente se conecta..siempre que esten dentro de la misma red wiffi(internet).. y que la PC1 tenga habilitado el puerto 80  para acceder desde cualquier lugar..

Comment: ¿Estas intentando con [https://dominio.local](https://dominio.local)?

Comment: Gracias...así está, pero al entrar desde el PC2, entra en el directorio htdocs, en vez del directorio del dominio...

Comment: Sí. Sal. Falla tanto con http como con https